# Pre-populating a form field from a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm trying to pre-populate a string field in a form when a link is clicked. I've tried:

```
$<%= link_to "New product", new_product_path(:product_name => "foo") %>
```

and

```
$<%= link_to "New product", new_product_path(:name => "foo") %>
```

Both didn't work. Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Does this link_to pass a params[:name] = 'foo' to the page?

Comment: Okay so Amar's solution must work or you ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this,
`<%= f.text_field :name,:value=>(@product.new_record? ? params[:name] : @product.name )%>`
or in new action

```
def new
@product = Product.new(:name=>params[:name])
end
<%= f.text_field :name %>
```

Comment: I only want the field to be pre-populated when a specific link is clicked, instead of whenever a new product is created.

Comment: use first method,`<%= f.text_field :name,:value=>params[:name] %>`

Comment: But if I define it in the form, the value shows up everytime. I only want the value to show when the user came to the form from a specific link. How do I define that value from the <%= link_to %>?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is best done from the controller. You can control what you send via the `link_to` as before.

```rb
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @product = Product.new new_product_params
  end
  
  def new_product_params
    params.permit :name, :another_field
  end
end
```

Answer (score -2):

Is the field you're trying to populate on the current page, or the target page?

If it is on the current page you'll need some javascript to accomplish that, if its on the
 target page you should probably set the default in your action based on passed parameters.